# How to add multiple blocked dates color in airbnb calendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

How can i add multiple blocked dates color in Reactjs airbnb calendar api?

ex:

- Red = special holiday
- Grey = unavailable
- blue = special non-working holiday

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderDayContents method. For example:

```
<DateRangePicker
  renderDayContents={(day) => {
    if (day.format('DD-MM') === '19-07')
      return <td className={classes.specialHoliday}>{day.format('DD')}</td>;
    if (day.format('DD-MM') === '18-07')
      return <td className={classes.unavailable}>{day.format('DD')}</td>;
    if (day.format('DD-MM') === '20-07')
      return (
        <td className={classes.specialNonWorkingHoliday}>
          {day.format('DD')}
        </td>
      );
    return <td>{day.format('DD')}</td>;
  }}
  ..........
/>
```

[image]